# Incorrect datetime value while saving data to MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I faced a strange problem about saving java `Date` object to MySql db. Here is the error I get:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 02:55:00' for column 'start_time' at row 1
```

My sql script

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules` (
            `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL,
            `end_time` timestamp NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Part of my entity:

```
 @Column(name = "start_time")
 private Date startTime;
```

When I try to do something like

```
String time = "02:55"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
scheduleEntity.setStartTime(sdf.parse(time));

repository.save(scheduleEntity);
```

It falls with error. But when I use `"16:00"` string for parsing it works perfectly. I use Spring Boot, Spring Data with Hibernate. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you just want to record time, not date and time, then use the `time` data type in MySQL, not a timestamp.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! I tested and it works. Can you post it as full answer with some short helpful comments on how to store time and map it to java? Thanks in advance! @Shadow

Comment: could you try this sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you want to store only a time portion in your table, yet you use `timestamp` data type, which stores both date and time and has other special features as well.

If you want to store time only, then use MySQL's [time data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or 'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

The linked documentation contains a link that explains how [time literals are interpreted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: And what is the corresponding type for mapping in java? `java.util.Date`?
When I persist it, my console logs contains WARN message `Incorrect time value: '1970-01-01 00:10:00' for column 'start_time' at row 1`

Comment: I believe you need to use the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)` annotation to mark that the column is of time data type, or use `java.sql.Time` as the java data type. But I'm no real expert on java and hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

Your column type is TIMESTAMP

[11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

**Solution**
you can change start_time and end_time columns type to DATETIME directly in DB or drop table and change you entity like this

```
@Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;
```

hope it will help

Comment: But '1970-01-01 02:55:00' is after '1970-01-01 00:00:01'. So what is the problem?

Comment: I guess it depends on your timezone, e.g. if +4 it is before than '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC

Comment: Hi Daniyar. You saved me. This was the reason why `preparedStatement.setTimestamp(paramIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(0))` wasn't working. Though I can't get what's happening `update.setTimestamp(paramIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(3601000))` works for me (below doesn't). It is GMT+1h+1sec. Hmmm?!?